# Is there a more database agnostic way to write this default scope in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, database-agnostic, default-scope

I have the following default scope defined in one of my models

```
default_scope order("IF(format = #{FORMATS[:wide]}, 1, 0) DESC, created_at DESC, name ASC")
```

It worked fine on my dev machine where I'm running MySQL, but borked when deployed to production where we use postgres. Is there a way to write that using Arel instead of straight SQL? `FORMATS[:wide]` returns an integer, but it may not be in any particular order. I just want records with that particular `format` to be returned first.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't put that in SQL at all.  I would probably make a scope for each format type and then use Ruby to determine which to use.  Or create a method that determines the sort order and passes that to wherever you are using it.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I can always select each format separately and then join them in a single array in the order I need them. Seems like it would be more efficient to have the DB do what it's built to do though.